# IntelliJ Idea can not run spring boot with gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I built a spring boot project .It used gradle 4.9,JDK 1.8 and idea .but I can't run the application

Build.gradle

```
 buildscript { 
 ext {
     springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'

 } 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    } 
dependencies {
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
plugin:${springBootVersion}")

   }

} 
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' group = 'com.example' 
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' 
sourceCompatibility = 1.8 repositories 
 { 
   mavenCentral()

 } 
   dependencies {
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') 
   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 }
```

**Error**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you show your **build.gradle** file?

Comment: post your code @user